# Button not firing in user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have a master page that has a drop down menu which displays a different User control depending on the menu choice.

Inside of the User control I'm trying to add a submit button that processes the inputted forms inside the user controls using the "_Click()" event handler. My user control aspx looks like the following:

```
<asp:Button ID="configBttn" runat="server" OnClick="configBttn_Click" AutoEventWireUp="true" />
```

and then I have the following in the codebehind:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {


   }

   protected void configBttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Response.Write("Hello world");
   }
```

I have even tried to add an event handler:

```
configBttn.Click += new EventHandler(configBttn_Click)
```

However this is still not allowing for the button to be triggered. Any ideas?

I add the user control inside the codebehind inside a div container:

`divContainer.Controls.Add(pPage.LoadControl("~/Controls/Control.ascx"));`

Comment: how did you add the usercontrol to the page? in the aspx file hardcoded? or in the code behind?

Comment: @JPHellemons I add it dynamically in the codebehind and not hardcoded. I just load it into a div

Comment: @user1326876 you cannot load a control into a div - you can add an instance, loaded via `.LoadControl()`, to the `Controls`-property of eg. a `Panel`. At which life-cycle step you are doing this?

Comment: or a placeholder. But in your page load of the masterpage it does re-create the dropdown and all other controls. So the page does not know that there was a usercontrol visible before and that there was a button to press.

Comment: @Andreas, I think you can add server tags to just about any html tag..and it turns it into a GenericHtmlContainer..

Comment: @BrettCaswell ... what is going on? where did we talk about tags? tags are not considered loading, as this will go a completely different branch ... :)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Hello - Do you have a suggestion that I can use?

Comment: @user1326876 yes, elaborate on the asked life-cycle step of doing `.LoadControl()` and `Controls.Add()`! There's a fairly good chance that you a) are missing this on a postback b) are too late to attach eventHandlers, which get invoked (last time) @ 2ndTryPostBack or c) the id is not the same anymore, so triggering the buttons eventHandler is not possible anymore, as the whole control-tree is different ...

Comment: what I'm saying is.. he is probably exposing the divContainer to his pageBehind in his content aspx page by adding the runat="server" on the div tag.. so it is possible to add controls to a div..

Comment: In deed, the lifecycle is in question here..

Comment: @BrettCaswell sry, first off: re-read the question where the OP talks about doing `.LoadControl()` and `Controls.Add()` :) and what i am trying to say: there's a huge difference between `.LoadControl()` and `<.... runat="server" />`

Comment: @user132, what controls are being initialized in the master page (outside of the contentplaceholder templates sections), and what controls are part of the content page? We obviously need more source code ot review..

Comment: @BrettCaswell Hey - I don't have access to the master page.. So I don't really know..

Comment: @user1326876 How can we help then?!

Comment: you might find use from this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dct97kc3(v=vs.100).aspx  (explains the lifecycle of masterpage and content pages).. also here a reference on how to programmatically work with masterpage and contentpages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c8y19k6h(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Where are you creating the UserControl in the Page Lifecycle?

I suspect that it needs to be created in the Init method of its container page.

In addition, they should not be wrapped in a !IsPostback block, or else when the page posts back, the control event handler is not mapped, so nothing is there to catch the click event.

Comment: Updated my OP I add the user control inside the codebehind

Comment: since you are using masterpages there are at least 2 codebehind areas. The one for the masterpage and the one for the contentpage (default.aspx .. or whatever the actual page you're requesting) (there has to be a content page).. which one are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code that adds the user control, I'm guessing that it is not saved as part of the page's view state. Which means when you click the button inside the user control the whole page gets refreshed and the user control is either not created or a different instance of it is created.